# IOS button on the XIB interface won't work

Tags: ios, swift

So am trying to implement a login/sign up segment control with a uiview which contains two subviews initialized with two viewcontroller (with xib files). I got this idea from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e5nxg5NzLks video and I put all elements on xib interface. However, the button won't work even though I set it correctly.

```
class RegisterLoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: BetterSegmentedControl!
@IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!
var subviews : [UIView]!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("this is main page superview")

    //change the value of segmented control
    segmentedControl.segments = LabelSegment.segments(withTitles: ["Login", "Sign Up"],
                                                      normalFont: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 20.0)!,
                                                      normalTextColor:  Utilities.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "FEC341"),
                                                      selectedFont: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Heavy", size: 20.0)!,
                                                      selectedTextColor: .white)
    //initialize login and signup subview
    subviews = [UIView]()
    subviews.append(LoginVC().view)
    subviews.append(SignUpVC().view)
    // add subviews to container
    for v in subviews{
        container.addSubview(v)
        //add subview constraints to be framed inside container
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.topAnchor).isActive = true
        v.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    //set login subview as default
    container.bringSubviewToFront(subviews[0])

}

// when the segmented control was selected
@IBAction func segmentedCtrlChanged(_ sender: BetterSegmentedControl) {
    self.container.bringSubviewToFront(subviews![Int(sender.index)])

}
}
```

the above is my main page view controller, and below is my login subview controller

```
import UIKit

class LoginVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var forgetPasswordLink: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("omg!")

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

    @IBAction func forgetPasswordTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("normal button works")
    }
}
```

I have also attached the login subview xib and file owner screenshot

[fileowner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XxPi.png)
[subview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRmXE.png)

Comment: right now, if i click forget password, there will be nothing print on the debug area which is not right.

Comment: I don't see a single line of code that suggests that you have a Xib file.

Comment: @El Tomato by following that video, I created xib when i created view controller. And all xib is xml file so i didn't attach. I saw some video and it usually to create xib with view file. so this is a bit weird

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at this link on how to implement a segmented view controller. Since you are new to iOS you will also get to know the minor details. https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, it is quite different from what i implemented so far and maybe i should implement in that way described in the article...

Answer (score -1):

I am the guy who posted question and I just somehow find a nasty ugly solution but at least it worked inspired by the video author's next video.

so I actually access the login view controller instance from main view controller, and access its button outlet and when I switch the control, i added a target on that button instance and it worked.

But it is messy because all subview's controller work will be handled in the main view controller (not their own vc). Hope this give someone some insight to help me find the bug and help me find a better solution.

Thank you

Comment: The problem is that a line like `subviews.append(LoginVC().view)` is both illegal and silly.  You cannot just plop a view controller’s view into your interface like that. For one thing, the view controller dies instantly, which is why the button doesn’t work.